# Why is there a だ in もっとだ?

Tags: grammar, translation, copula, anime

I am watching a certain show at the moment where someone is talking about wanting to kill evil creatures. Please don't judge this question as childish just because the extract is from an anime.

He says

> くちくしてやる。この世から。一匹残らず

I understand that, but then he says

> **もっとだ**。もっと。もっと殺したい。

I don't understand why he would say もっと**だ**. The reason why is that I don't know what he is saying exists as 「もっと...」, if you understand what I mean. I know the meaning of the word, I just don't get why he would say だ afterwards.
Like, if I asked in Japanese I would say... 何が「もっと」ですか？
What would replace 何 in that question?

Is だ just emphasis of how much he wants to kill more?

Answer (score 3):

Pulling from http://kurotoxxx.exblog.jp/20636377:

> 駆逐、してやる!　この世から、一匹残らず...
> I'll exterminate 'em! From this world, with not a single one remaining...
>
> もっとだ!
> More!
>
> もっと... もっと殺す!　殺したい。
> More... Kill more! I want to kill them.
>
> もっと、いっぱい... 殺してやる...
> With more, full-on-ness (for lack of a better word)... I'll kill 'em...

I believe "もっとだ" does emphasize the "もっと殺す" to make it stronger as "もっと" comes immediately before "殺す" in the following sentence - I'm pretty sure "もっと殺す!" needs to follow to make it clear what the "もっとだ！" refers to here.

"もっとだ！" by itself without following context could mean "give (me/it etc) more!" in an informal and stronger way than "もっと！", or "it's more (than something)" etc.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. Do you think it would be possible to say もっとです in a way that uses the word as "more" not just referring to it as an actual word?

Comment: If like the pattern "もっとです！もっと..." (e.g. "もっとです！もっと殺します！") I think you can. Whether "もっとです！" by itself works in that way and whether you can transfer this "...だ！..."/"...です！..." pattern to other expressions I'm not sure.