# Do people use 駆逐 in general to mean "exterminate"?

Tags: meaning

In episode 25 of Attack of the Titan anime, the protagonist said

> 駆逐してやる…いや、殺す (yelling very loudly)

Now, "exterminate" seems to be a pretty common translation of 駆逐, for example

- [JMDict](http://beta.jisho.org/word/51859a98d5dda7295400b49a) defines it as "Extermination; expulsion; destruction."
- [A Stack Exchange post by cypher](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12488/6840) mentions a translation which uses "exterminate" for 駆逐.
- 駆逐艦 means destroyer.

---

Despite that, [大辞泉・大辞林](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A7%86%E9%80%90) defines them along the lines of

> 敵などを追い払うこと

i.e. "to drive (enemy etc.) away; to get rid of"

[研究社 新和英中辞典](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A7%86%E9%80%90) also uses words like

> drive away [out]; oust; expel; get rid of

for 駆逐(する), but never "exterminate".

---

So, I wonder if it's correct to say that 駆逐 means "to exterminate" or "to destroy", or if such a meaning is only inferred indirectly from the context. An example in English is "to get rid". Usually we won't think of "get rid" as killing, at least not *specifically*, right? Or rather, killing is but one of the many ways of getting rid of something. But say

> That guy's asking too much questions. Get rid of him.

and you would associate "get rid = kill".

Is this the same case with 駆逐?

---

Seems like 駆逐 is used very often in military context. For what it's worth, here are some in non-military context I've come across

- [スマートフォン、タブレットがパソコンを駆逐する？](http://pc.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/column/20110830/1036534/)
- [動物駆逐用煙火（連続発射式）の取扱いにご注意ください！](http://www.safety-hokkaido.meti.go.jp/sangyo_hoan/kayaku/caution/index140729.htm)
- [直訳文を駆逐せよ](http://japanenglish.jp/column/%E7%9B%B4%E8%A8%B3%E6%96%87%E3%82%92%E9%A7%86%E9%80%90%E3%81%9B%E3%82%88.html)

Comment: In my own words, extermination = intensive type of 駆逐, not plain 駆逐.

Answer (score 5):

I think 「駆逐する」 is stronger than *get rid*, but not as strong as *exterminate*.

Literally speaking, 駆 means to *drive*, and 逐 means to *chase*. As 大辞泉 says, there is no meaning of *killing* or *destroying* explicitly included in this word.

However, 駆逐 is almost always used in a military context, and usually implies *killing* or *destroying*, as the simplest measure to keep enemies away.

And I feel *every last one* or *all* is also implied in 駆逐 (getting rid of every last enemy). In this sense, *extermination* is not too far. That said, killing is not necessarily required.

> 駆逐してやる…いや、殺す

In this sentence, I think the speaker is already not hesitating to kill the enemies by saying 駆逐してやる. And with 殺す, the speaker explicitly denies the enemies' chance of survival.

Comment: You are definitely right about 駆逐's usage in military context. I had to use `"駆逐" -"駆逐艦" -"駆逐してやる" -"駆逐戦車" -"駆逐隊" -"駆逐車" -"駆逐艇" -"進撃の巨人"` in Google to find non-military contexts.

Comment: One use that I see here and there is 動物駆逐, for example this PDF ["動物駆逐用煙火（連続発射式）の取扱いにご注意ください！
" by METI](http://www.meti.go.jp/press/2014/07/20140725004/20140725004a.pdf). These mean "chasing away" rather than "kill", right?

Comment: でも「方言が駆逐される」とか「プログラムからバグを駆逐する」みたいな使い方もします。害虫・害獣を殺す場合は普通「駆逐」より「駆除」を使いますね。

Comment: naruto's answers are always great. I wanted to say thank you for helping out people out of your own time.